# Parsing JSON with multiple tuples to List<object> in scala

Tags: json, scala, jerkson

```
[
{"fname":"Foo","lname":"Pacman"},
{"fname":"Bar","lname":"Mario"},
{"fname":"Poo","lname":"Wario"}
]
```

Well I have JSON string in this format, 
Now what I need is to convert each tuples -> `{"fname":"Foo","lname":"Pacman"}`

To a Person object,
for e.g. lets assume I have a case class

`case class Person(fname:String,lname:String)`

Now how am I to get, `List<person>`

If I had a JSON containing data for single tuple, then I could,

`val o:Person = parse[Person](jsonString)// I am actually using Jerkson Lib`

But since there are more than one tuples, how am i to parse them individually and create objects and create a list.

Comment: Have you tried `parse[List[Person]]`?  Doesn't that work?

Comment: Ya tried that just now and it works.... 
Funny , was a 1 line answer `val parsedList = parse[List[Person]](jsonString)`

Comment: given the minor syntax error at hand, consider deleting the question.

Comment: Ok, I will but dont you think some one might find it handy?? Like, how much time I looked around the web for this answer.

Comment: Then it should have a proper answer. @cmbaxter, would you put your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jerkson supports deserializing lists of objects out of the box, so all you should need to do is:

```
val people = parse[List[Person]](personJson)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [json4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s) (which is a wrapper around either jackson or lift-json) where you also get such parsing capabilities out of the box.

```
   import org.json4s._
   import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
   implicit val formats = DefaultFormats 

    val personJson = """
      [
      {"fname":"Foo","lname":"Pacman"},
      {"fname":"Bar","lname":"Mario"},
      {"fname":"Poo","lname":"Wario"}
      ]"""
    case class Person(fname:String,lname:String)
    val people = parse(personJson).extract[List[Person]]
```

Comment: umm, will give json4s a try too for my next projects, since Jerkson doesn't seem to be actively developed, thanks for the answer

Comment: I am using it myself now, seems to be fine. success with your projects :)